# Why multi-process could not speedup sending HTTP requests via eventlet

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, eventlet

I have an app to send a bunch of HTTP requests. First, I use **eventlet** and **requests** to implement it. But the performance is too low. Hence, I expected to speed it up using multi-process. A thing need to know is that the server will takes about **200ms** to handle a single request (no including network transfer).

However, the multi-process is slower than the original version. I feel so amazed about this result! Why?

The code as following shown, I used **timeit** to measure time.

```
import eventlet
eventlet.monkey_patch(all=False, socket=True)

import requests

URL = 'http://....'

def send():
    pile = eventlet.GreenPile(20)
    for x in xrange(100):
        pile.spawn(requests.get, URL)
    for x in pile:
        pass

import multiprocessing

def main():
    procs = [multiprocessing.Process(target=send) for _ in range(3)]
    for p in procs:
        p.start()
    for p in procs:
        p.join()

import timeit

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print timeit.timeit(main, number=1)
```

Comment: I've not fully reasoned through the code, but you're using `multiprocessing` which has an expensive upfront cost for process creation but allows multiple cores to perform computation in parallel, on a problem that is I/O bound.  Threads may be a better solution as long as the bottleneck is purely I/O.

Comment: @zehnpaard, I also have tried multi-thread, and the result is the same as multi-process. any idea about such result?

Comment: Actually `eventlet.GreenPile`'s `spawn` creates green threads anyway, so it's probably duplicative to use threads or processes on top of `eventlet`.  I/O requests to the server are already being handled in parallel.

Comment: @zehnpaard, does it mean that even multi-process will share a single IO loop provided by kernel?

Comment: No, it's the reverse issue - even in your original code, when you weren't using `multiprocessing`, the `eventlet` module was already giving you concurrent I/O, so using another concurrency pattern (whether they are processes or threads) isn't helping.

Comment: @zehnpaard, I still do not understand why. Although eventlet has provide concurrent I/O, multi-process could still take advantage of multi-cpu and thus gain better performance. What mistake I made?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70361/discussion-between-jacky-and-zehnpaard).

Comment: @Jacky multiprocessing will only give more performance if single core performance is 100% busy. Which is hard to achieve using eventlet and HTTP requests.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: not enough information. **By pure speculation**, the server is the limiting factor (which may be caused by intentional artificial limits or resource starvation), so by adding more concurrent requests you are making each slower on average.

Here's one way to reason about this: you have limited amount of resources on both client and server: CPU cycles per time, memory accesses per time, memory size, network bandwidth. OS and eventlet make reasonable use of these resources. Such that you can do estimates on how much resources it takes to make a single request and software will scale it out in a reasonable pattern (that is close to linear). To benefit from multiprocessing would require your client process makes single CPU unit 100% busy. And specifically `requests` library is known to be good at wasting hardware resources, it incurs the most CPU overhead of all I tried (httplib, httplib2, urllib). But you have to make really lots (thousands) of concurrent requests or have really bad/busy CPU to make it bottleneck.

Exact answer requires information:

- Whether HTTP client and server concur for any resources? I.e. do they run on same physical hardware?
- What is the maximum request frequency (count per second) you were able to generate in single process mode? Adjust GreenPile size to vary number of concurrent requests.
- What is the maximum frequency of requests you were able to generate using multiple processes? Adjust both GreenPile size and number of processes. Try running several independent Python interpreters without multiprocessing.
- Was server the bottleneck? Check by adding another client on separate hardware. If request frequency is higher then the server is not bottleneck. If request frequency drops with more clients, then the server was already running at limit and multiprocessing could only help to make things worse.
- What is the request time distribution? What percentage of requests was completed in 220/300/400/500/1000/more ms?
- What is network latency/bandwidth? What is request/response size? Do you saturate network then?

Answering these questions will provide you with excellent intuition on what's going on inside and between your client/server.

Relevant Github issue: https://github.com/eventlet/eventlet/issues/195

Comment: thanks for your reply. I answered the questions one by one 1. the server and the client are in different location. 2. the time used to send a fixed number of requests is almost the same no matter the GreenPile size is 10, 20 or 200. 3. the server could accept more requests in one second. I have used apache ab test it, the ab could run 10 times faster than the eventlet version. 4. not sure  5. the request/response size is less than 256 bytes. A thing to say is that, it is HTTPS protocol.

Comment: @Jacky please do the following test with different pool sizes: run 100-1000 requests and measure CPU usage of client process from start to stop. If unsure how to measure CPU usage, you may use GNU time (usually installed as /usr/bin/time) or cpu_usage function from eventlet tests https://github.com/eventlet/eventlet/blob/master/tests/__init__.py#L189